# SPFx on Terminal Server

Tags: spfx

I have been setting up a terminal server, for development for our team. However i am having a hard time making the SPFx envoriment (Gulp / Yeoman) work.

I would love to install Yeoman and Gulp so it just works for everyone, however it beeing installed in the %appdata% directory is an issue here. Is it posible to install Yeoman and Gulp globally? npm install -g yo gulp, does not seem to install globally, or maby it is just me misunderstanding the parameter ?

Answer (score 0):

SPFx development is not meant to be done using a terminal server. The SharePoint framework is built for *local* development. Each developer should run `npm install -g yo gulp` on their machine, following all the instructions at [Set Up Your SharePoint Development Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment). Each dev can run their solution locally and debug it using the SharePoint Workbench. Both the local and the SharePoint workbench can use locally hosted SPFx components.

If your team is used to using SharePoint Designer, this is a significant change.